# Configure connection leasing strategy (fifo/lifo) for httpclient Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-gateway, reactor-netty

Spring Cloud Gateway provides a way to configure httpclient property like

```
spring:
   application:
   cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 1000
        response-timeout: 5s
        pool:
          maxIdleTime: 15s
```

I don't see any property for connection leasing strategy through which I can change it to lifo (default is fifo).

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactor Netty provides system property `reactor.netty.pool.leasingStrategy` that can be used for changing this setting. See more in the [Reference Documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_connection_pool_2).

Spring Gateway gives you also the possibility to change the `HttpClient` via `@Bean`.